# hh:mm:ss to hh:mm sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I saw similar questions, but somehow it doesn't work for me.

I have `cast(arrival as time)` which gives me time in hh:mm:ss format, and I want only hh:mm. I tried `CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),cast(arrival as time), 108)` and I get error.

`arrival` is `datetime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tried both but once try,

```
DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%H:%i')
```

Let me know, if its working

Comment: I will, just have to wait 7 more minutes :)

Comment: Ohh, I see :D ! :)